# subdivision surface modifier crashes when i use it

Tags: subdivision-surface

The subdivision surface modifier in pretty much all versions of blender except for 2.8 crash as soon as I use them. I'm currently using a lenovo thinkpad t450 if that helps anyone find the issue. The update i'm using is blender 3.5. I have tried updating my computer re-installing blender or updating blender but nothing has worked so far. [fixed]

Comment: That sounds suspiciously as if you're running out of memory. What is the specification of your laptop? - I've never heard of a subdiv modifier crashing a machine although I suppose it could happen if you're short of memory and are using a very high Viewport Level on the modifier. There was a question about viewport lag a few days ago and it turned out that the user had his level set to 5 although it didn't crash the machine.

Comment: This is a pure guess, but quick to eliminate.. are you using GPU subdivision (set in preferences) https://imgur.com/a/xZms4if ?

Comment: danke sehr mein freund, gpu subdiv was on, i turned it off and it worked